# How do I fix this blurry effect on a .mkv video in VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

Basically, whenever the camera moves or something in the frame moves, I get these weird horizontal lines. I linked 2 images where you can see this really well. If you look at the first image you really well see how blurry the white poles are. The second image is a comparison when the camera is still.

The first is really weird blurry, the second one is normal. And I'm not talking about the fact that video quality decreases when something moves. I'm talking about those horizontal lines.

How can I solve this issue?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2):

Horizontal lines are usually due to interlacing issues. [VLC has a de-interlace setting](https://wiki.videolan.org/deinterlacing) which is used to correct this.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the decomb filter in handbrake to permanently repair the video.